# How to realize any non-crossing matching as $\mathrm{Re}[p(z)]=0$

Tags: co.combinatorics, polynomials

Asymptotically any polynomial is $p(z) = z^n + O(z^{n-1})$.  Therefore $\mathrm{Re}[p(z)]= r^n \cos(2\pi i \theta)$ which vanishes at $\theta = \frac{(k+ \frac{1}{2})\pi}{n}$.  Those $2n$ line segments need to connect in some fashion giving a non-crossing.

Conversely, can we construct at $p(z)$ realizing any non-crossing matching?

Answer (score 7):

Yes. See [Martin, Savitt and Singer](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0511248) for much more: Any topologically reasonable (see their paper for details) pattern of $n$ crosses can be realized as $\{ z : \mathrm{Re}(p(z)) = 0 \} \cup \{ z : \mathrm{Im}(p(z)) = 0 \}$. They also have statements for more than $2$ angles.

Remark: You only get curves if you assume that $\{ z : p'(z) = 0 \}$ doesn't lie on any of the curves you care about. See [Eremenko and Gabrielov](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0512370) for a beautiful result about rational functions where these curves do pass through the critical points.